# What meant by DescribeFieldResult Class?

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql, describefieldresult

Can anyone clearly explain what exact use of `DescribeFieldResult` Class in Apex code. And also please provide an example.

Answer (score 3):

The DescribeFieldResult Class contains methods which provide you the metadata info about a field on a sObject from which you have fetched the `DescribeFieldResult` instance:

For example:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult =
                                  Schema.SObjectType.Custom_Object__c.fields.Status__c;
```

If you have a close look at the documentation of `DescribeFieldResult` class available in the [Salesforce docs](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm), you will see that you get the length of the field, if its a formula field then you can even get the formula within that field, the default value etc.

There could be multiple use cases wherein you would need such information:

One sample use case might be to create a `Select * from...` SQL equivalent in SOQL. This is explained very well in a blog [here](http://salesforcesource.blogspot.in/2012/05/get-best-out-of-apex-describe-methods.html).

Another use case would be to fetch the metadata from each of the fields of the object and compare it with another to figure out the difference (ex: record or object metadata comparison in sandbox vs prod)
This [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/record-and-metadata-compa/laghgcpekjofijkmojnhfeiplbffaljp?hl=en-US) relies heavily on such metadata returned by the DescribeFieldResult class and shows you the difference between two records/objects and their metadata.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In a object I have created a picklist feild ,but the pick list values are stored in translation settings  can i get those values using these methods

Comment: And also explain schema class what is use in sales force ?

Comment: for translation settings i guess metadata api is the only option http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm#pickListValueTranslation

Comment: The schema class is used to get the metadata of your entire salesforce org, imagine accessing any object, any fields on those objects, extracting datatype info, tabs etc.

Comment: I just found this "Use toLabel(fields) to translate SOQL query results into the user’s language" see if you can use this to get the translated piclist values http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_tolabel.htm